# When to drop "um" in um-zu constructions?

Tags: preposition

> Ich liebe Katzen  in jeder Gestalt und Größe und werde ihnen helfen, **um** ein gutes Leben zu führen.

I wrote this sentence for a writing exercise in German. A native told me that I should drop the "um" in the sentence after the comma. They gave the following explanation.

> „um zu + Infinitiv“ leitet einen Nebensatz ein, der nur dann funktioniert, wenn das Subjekt im Hauptsatz und im Nebensatz gleich sind. Das kannst du überprüfen, indem du beide Satzteile getrennt formulierst: Ich werde ihnen helfen. + Die Katzen führen ein gutes Leben.

I don't grasp the idea behind of the explanation. Could someone give a more detailed explanation of this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're asking the question the wrong way around. There are *zu* infinitive constructions, and sometimes these have *um* added. The *um* translates roughly to "so that" or "in order to". A *zu* infinitive is frequently used with *helfen*, meaning "to help (to do something)". In this case you're helping the cats have a good life. With *um* the sentence means something like you're helping the cats in order to have a good life, and as pointed out in the comments, that doesn't really make sense.